# How to transfer Data from One SQL server to another with out transactional replication

Tags: sql, sql-server, apache-kafka, data-stream

I have a database connected with website, data from website is inserting in that Database, i need to transfer data from that database to another Primary Database (SQL) on another server in real time (minimum latency). 
I can not use transactional replication in this case. What are the other alternates to achieve this? Can i integrate DataStreams like Apache kafka etc with SQL server?

Comment: Why can you not use transactional replication in this case? What are the limiting factors/constraints to consider in giving an answer here?

Comment: There are multiple factors i can not use transactional replication. one is transactional replication will make my primary DB read only, however there are other applications connected with that DB,

Answer (score 0):

Without more detail it's hard to give a full answer. There's what's technically possible, and there's architecturally what actually makes sense :)

Yes you can stream from RDBMS to Kafka, and from Kafka to RDBMS. You can use the [Kafka Connect JDBC source and sink](http://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-jdbc/). There are also CDC tools (e.g. Attunity, GoldenGate, etc) that support integration with MS SQL and other RDBMS)

BUT…it depends why you want the data in the second database. Do you need an exact replica of the first? If so DB-DB replication may be a better option. Kafka's a great option if you want to process the data elsewhere and/or persist it in another store. But if you just want MS SQL-MS SQL…Kafka itself may be overkill.

Comment: Yes, i need an exact replica of the DB. Actually DB connected with website is subset of primary DB, Primary DB is already connected with Other applications which are inserting/updating data in that DB, 
I need to Get Data from web DB and insert in Primary DB where that Data will be available to other Applications.

Comment: So either:  (1) modify your apps to write directly to Kafka INSTEAD of the database, and then stream from Kafka to as many targets for the data as you would like OR (2) forget about Kafka and just invest in SQL Server replication technology